# No encuentro como decirle al la variable btn_reenviar que si no existe que siga intentando

Tags: python

Cambie la tupla y me sale el siguiente error
or("'bool' object has no attribute 'exists'"), <traceback object at 0x000002750A191740>)

```
            msg_forward = [
                self.d(description="Forward button")
            ]

            msg_error_forward = [
                self.d.xpath('//*[@content-desc="Back"]').exists,
                self.d.press("back"),
                self.d.open_url(fanpage_url)
            ]

            busqueda = []
            for element in msg_forward:
                busqueda.append(element)

            for element in msg_error_forward:
                busqueda.append(element)

            time.sleep(1)
            objectoEncontrado = UiWait.for_any(busqueda, 10)
            if objectoEncontrado:
                if objectoEncontrado in msg_forward:
                    if self.d.press("back"):
                        self.d.open_url(fanpage_url)
            else:            
                if objectoEncontrado in msg_forward:
                    if msg_forward.exists:
                        msg_forward.click()

                break

if btn_reenviar.exists:

btn_reenviar.click()
```

quiero que haga lo siguiente si no encuentra el boton que de atras y vuelva y entre hasta que encuentre en btn_reenviar

Comment: Haz probado con un bucle `while`?

Comment: no conozco el while por eso busco ayuda

Comment: `while btn_reenviar.not_exist: self.d.press("back")`

Comment: aun esa no me soluciona el problema

Comment: Pues trata de investigar en base a lo que te dije y ele ejemplo que mostré, luego edita la pregunta y añade lo que intentaste y el problema concreto que tienes. Si hay errores por consola también ponlos en la pregunta.

Comment: AttributeError("'UiObject' object has no attribute 'not_exists'"), <traceback object at 0x00000283C27F0A00>)

Comment: [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/531967/edit) tu pregunta y añade más detalles. Ni siquiera sé que módulo estás usando, si lo haces con `request`, `beautifoulSoup` o `Selenium`. Así sin más no puedo ayudarte.